# HAProxy: Unable to set chipper list - possible bug?

Tags: ssl, haproxy

I have two machines running with similar configuration. Both have an HAProxy installed.

Now I want to enable native SSL Termination. This works perfectly on Server one. Now on Server 2 I cant get it running and keep getting this error message:

```
Restarting haproxy haproxy                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

[ALERT] 231/185237 (5179) : Proxy 'apache-https': unable to set SSL cipher list to 'ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:$' for bind '192.168.56.150:443' at [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:102].
[ALERT] 231/185237 (5179) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
```

Config seems to be equal as on server2

Is this possibly a bug? Almost impossible as I have done the installation simultaniously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a `$` character at the end of your cipher list. Removing it and the last colon should allow it to work.

```
ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:$
```

Becomes

```
ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES
```

Comment: Just compared the two configs of HAProxy. The faulty one has indeed 4 characters in the end which the working one does not have. Copy Pasted it to the broken one and it works! The dollar sign is still there. Funny stuff as both are installed from here: add-apt-repository ppa:vbernat/haproxy-1.5